# Send email about status of cron job completion

Tags: linux, ubuntu, email, shell-script

I have some scripts that do usual stuff like backing up MySql database, gz, tar some files and put them on FTP or sync with some other backup/mirror system. Some scripts are running quite frequently (like twice/thrice per hour). I am sending email with attached log output from commands after completion of job. It is quite a lot of email to keep track of.

I want to send email only when script fails to do something, that is when some command in script fails. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the return value of the command and proceed accordingly. Normally all the **Linux commands return 0 on success and some other number(specifying the reason) on failure**.

**Update:**
Forgot to mention that the status of last command is saved in variable "`$?`". Thanks @bbaja42

Comment: suppose I run a command using `curl` like `curl --upload-file.....` in a script how will I check status? `i = curl --upload-file...` then `if [i eq 0]`?

Comment: Status of last command is saved in variable "$?", so you can use [ $? -eq 0 ]

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot: [Example.](https://gist.github.com/a9fb07473bb522fbc9f2)

Comment: @bbaja42 and @grawity thanks for clearing up the things. I'm accepting @ssapkota's answer.

Answer (score 0):

here is an example of script that I wrote for my work that's being used on daily basis

```
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 ~]$ sudo cat /usr/local/uftwf/mysql/_mysql.sh
#!/bin/sh
# $Id: _mysql.sh,v 1.2 2011/05/31 16:02:56 alexus Exp $

if [ -d /var/lib/mysql/ ]; then
    cd /var/lib/mysql/
    for i in `ls`; do
            /usr/bin/mysqldump \
                --user=root \
                $i > /usr/local/uftwf/mysql/$i.sql
            /bin/gzip \
                --force \
                --quiet \
                /usr/local/uftwf/mysql/$i.sql
    done
    /usr/bin/mysqladmin \
        --user=root \
        flush-logs
    /usr/bin/mysql \
        --user=root \
        --execute='PURGE BINARY LOGS BEFORE subdate(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 DAY);'
fi
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 ~]$ 


[alexus@wcmisdlin02 ~]$ sudo crontab -l -u mysql
@daily      /usr/local/uftwf/mysql/_mysql.sh
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 ~]$
```

it will only email you once you get some sort of an error, it will *not* mail if job ran ok. This shell script resides in /usr/local/uftwf/mysql and that's where backups goes as well. Modify this script to FTP/rsync files to your remote location.

Comment: Where's the conditional emailing bit?

Comment: This has a number of issues which http://shellcheck.net/ can easily diagnose.

Comment: @Linker3000 if there are no errors, nothing will be emailed

Comment: @tripleee script works and has been since 2011, didn't fail even once...

Comment: Good for you, I'm cautioning others that it might not work for them because of undocumented assumptions and portability issues.